# Reliable shutter feedback - Prontor contur (PC) or hotshoe

Tags: shutter, hotshoe

I use gigapan to take panorama photos. I prefer using autofocus even for panoramas. Sometimes (sky or other homogenous area) the camera fails to find the focus and does not take the photo. Gigapan moves on, one or more shot is missing (especially if I chat with people interested in the equipment).

Gigapan can receive the feedback of shutter operation through a dedicated socket. I use a 5DII camera. It has both a prontor contur and hotshoe that I can use for this purpose.

Which is the more reliable source of shutter feedback? I found opinions both being not reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the hot shoe, especially with panormas - I have had contact issues with PC flash connectors (even the screw lock kind) in the past; the connector isn't really mechanically robust.

Besides, a missed release confirmation isn't so bad: you might end up with false negatives (duplicate shots that the system repeated because it didn't get the confirmation), but you won't have any false positives (shots missed because the system sensed them as taken).